# Debugging Ansible modules

Tags: ansible

I tried to write an Ansible module. My module is buggy. When I run it from a playbook I get the following unreadable output:

```
$ ansible-playbook lacp.yml 

PLAY [xxxxxxxx] ****************************************************************

TASK [Test that my module works] ***********************************************
fatal: [xxxxxxxx]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "module_stderr": "couldn't set locale correctly\ncouldn't set locale correctly\ncouldn't set locale correctly\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_vHkWq8/ansible_module_lacp.py\", line 27, in <module>\n    main()\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_vHkWq8/ansible_module_lacp.py\", line 14, in main\n    m = re.match('^key: ([0-9]+) ', dladm.readline())\nAttributeError: 'Popen' object has no attribute 'readline'\ndladm: insufficient privileges\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "parsed": false}

NO MORE HOSTS LEFT *************************************************************
 [WARNING]: Could not create retry file 'lacp.retry'.         [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''


PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
xxxxxxxx                   : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

How to stop Ansible quoting error messages with JSON? Or is there another way to debug Ansible modules?

Answer (score 2):

> How to stop Ansible quoting error messages with JSON?

You can use [human_log.py](https://gist.github.com/cliffano/9868180) plugin to force Ansible to interpret and print newline characters in its output.

You put the file into `/path/to/callback_plugins/` directory and add the following to the `ansible.cfg`:

```
[defaults]
callback_plugins = /path/to/callback_plugins/
```

The detailed instructions are in the [Human-Readable Ansible Playbook Log Output Using Callback Plugin](http://blog.cliffano.com/2014/04/06/human-readable-ansible-playbook-log-output-using-callback-plugin/) blog post.

Answer (score 2):

You can look into [this](https://github.com/n0ts/ansible-human_log) and [this](https://gist.github.com/dmsimard/cd706de198c85a8255f6) callback plugins (for Ansible 2.x).
You will need to modify them a bit, because they don't convert `module_stderr` out of the box.

Also you may want to execute playbook with `ANSIBLE_KEEP_REMOTE_FILES=1`, then ssh to the remote box and debug your module in-place, then save to ansible library.

Answer (score 0):

Debugging Ansible modules will quickly become next to impossible and very, very time consuming without following the recommended approach.

The recommended approach is to build your Ansible stuff using very small steps. That way you can more easily guess what is wrong as you add stuff to what you know and have verified to work.

So when you state that the module is buggy, you have gone to far. You will be  searching for a needle in the haystack that Ansible without question is.

Refactoring is not really a practical option. You basically start fresh, recreating your code step by step.

I hope you noticed that Ansible doesn't even bother to format error output in a human readable way. In a way on error Ansible outputs the same message: something went wrong.

Let's say I have this Ansible task

```
- name: Mymodule
  mymodule:
    something: "something"
```

My module also is simple enough

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from ansible.module_utils.basic import *

    def somefunction(data):
      has_changed = False
      meta = { "something": "something"}
      return (has_changed, meta)
    def main():

      fields = {
        "something": {"required": True, "type": "str"}, 
        "state": {
              "default": "perform", 
              "choices": ["perform"],  
              "type": "str" 
            },        
          }
      choice_map = {
        "perform2": somefunction,
      }

      module = AnsibleModule(argument_spec=fields)
      has_changed, result = choice_map.get(module.params['state'])(module.params)
      module.exit_json(changed=has_changed, meta=result)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Ansible will produce the following error message

> TASK [backup : Mymodule]
>   ******************************************************* fatal: [myapp]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Shared
>   connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "Traceback
>   (most recent call last):\r\n  File
>   \"/home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1570188887.99-191548982937437/AnsiballZ_mymodule.py\",
>   line 114, in \r\n    _ansiballz_main()\r\n  File
>   \"/home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1570188887.99-191548982937437/AnsiballZ_mymodule.py\",
>   line 106, in _ansiballz_main\r\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod,
>   temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\r\n  File
>   \"/home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1570188887.99-191548982937437/AnsiballZ_mymodule.py\",
>   line 49, in invoke_module\r\n    imp.load_module('**main**', mod,
>   module, MOD_DESC)\r\n  File
>   \"/tmp/ansible_mymodule_payload_XTaVPp/**main**.py\", line 29, in
>   \r\n  File
>   \"/tmp/ansible_mymodule_payload_XTaVPp/**main**.py\", line 25, in
>   main\r\nTypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable\r\n", "msg":
>   "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}

The "message" we should focus on is

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

It is caused by the wrong action **perform2**. It should be **perform**. A simple typo.

```
      choice_map = {
        "perform2": somefunction,
      }
```

The typo is in module file **mymodule.py** on line 21. The files and lines 114, 106, 49, 29, 25 might be useful in someway but how these files are useful is not clear at all.

This is just a very simple example to illustrate the point of the haystack. Ansible does not format the error message in human readable way. Reporting on the problem file and line number is also not an exact science. And the error message is not useful. The error message should be that my choice_map is referencing a non-existing action. It could list the available choices.

IMHO this is a common problem with Ansible. A typing mistake can take a hour to fix.

The only way to workaround this limitation is to build up provision step by step. Baby steps.